# Grid based Clustering

Tags: here-api

I am trying to do a grid based clustering, specifically where each U.S. state is a grid. What I am doing now is just setting strategy option of **ClusterProvider** to **STRATEGY_GRID_BASED**, but I don't think this is what I think it is.

I tried looking into **nokia.maps.clustering.IGridOptions**, but there isn't anything documentation on that.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Grid-based clustering strategy** just breaks the map up into squares and calculates how many markers are found in each square. What you are after is known as a [**Chloropleth Map**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map). The most efficient way to do this would be to cluster server-side, return a key,value pair (i.e. state, number of markers) and just display polygons for the US States. An example of such a map can be found in the [HERE Maps community examples](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#wkt-parser__load-wkt-us-states) which displays the accession dates of states to the union.

If you insist on doing everything client side then you'd have to use the following pseudo code instead:

Iterate though each marker in your list:

1. Check to see if it is [within the hit area](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#is-point-within-a-polygon) of an existing `polygon`.
2. If it is - increment the markers counter (an additional attribute you have added.)
3. If it isn't make a WKT State-level shape geocoding request, and [parse the result](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#wkt-parser__region-shape-on-click) -add a new markers counter attribute to the `Polygon`
4. repeat

You will then end up with a series of `polygon` objects each holding an attribute with the number of markers within found within the state.

Comment: Thanks. ended up doing something similar but instead of polygons i just had two sets of markers. each for different zoom level.